How would you create those low-res abstract shapes?
I saw those kind of low-res shapes on a lot of posters (here circled in red, the grey shapes with a purple stroke) and I was wondering what's the best way to achieve them. I'm working with illustrator and I've tried drawing shapes with the pen tool and then pixelating them but it doesn't get quite the result I'm looking for. Thanks in advance !


take a look at "glitch art." they may have used auto-trace on analog glitch art

Make a grid of squares, black stroke, white fill. Select the entire grid, and use the Live Paint Bucket to make a pixel shape by dragging it over the pixels.

Once you have a shape, expand it and ungroup twice. Zoom in and select one pixel and then do Select > Same > Fill color. Cut the selection and paste somewhere else on screen.
Fill the inside with the Live Paint Bucket

Do Expand, and ungroup twice, then open the Path Finder and click Unite to make it one shape. Add a stroke, change the fill.


Amazing, thank you so much !
